# missing ) after argument list when using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React-router v0.13.3 and React 0.13.3 to build a simple web app.
But a big issue happened when I tried to integrate with React-Router.

So, here's error message:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

app.jsx

```js
  var Router = window.ReactRouter;
  var Route = Router.Route;

  app.VIEW_SEARCH = 'search_view';
  app.VIEW_FAVORITE = 'favorite_view';
  app.VIEW_RESULT = 'result_view';

  var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;
  var App = React.createClass({
    render () {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>App</h1>
          <RouteHandler/>
        </div>
      )
    }
  });

  // declare our routes and their hierarchy
  var routes = (
    <Route handler={App} path="/">
      <Route path="search" handler={app.SearchView}/>
      <Route path="about" handler={app.AboutView}/>
      <Router.DefaultRoute handler={app.SearchView}/>
    </Route>
  );

  Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, (Root) => {
    React.render(<Root/>, document.body);
  });
```

The main JavaScript codes pasted above, the error appeared when I added the last 3 lines. And the web app is using bower to manage the dependencies.

if I use

```
  Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function(handler) {
    React.render(<handler/>, document.body);
  });
```

to replace the last 3 lines. Nothing shows up on the screen.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Are you using babelify to translate the arrow function? Otherwise support in browsers is hit-or-miss.

Comment: @JeffFairley what's the babel solution? Haven't heard of it. I'm experiencing this same problem using `grunt-react`.

Comment: @crockpotveggies I'm using gulp, so I won't bother pasting my config, but you want to use the [babelify transformer](https://github.com/babel/babelify) when you run browserify. You may look at the [grunt-babel](https://github.com/babel/grunt-babel) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The parenthesis error is probably because of the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) you use. This is an ecmascript 6 feature and is not supported by most browsers for now unfortunately.

Since you use gulp, it would be very easy for you to add [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to your build steps. 
Otherwise, just use the 'old' notation: `function(Root) {return ...}`

As for the second issue you point in your comments, we would need the source code of `Root` to try to understand what's happening.